# Levenshtein distance on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

is there any official or "de-facto" official implementation of Levenshtein distance on MariaDB 10.2 or 10.3?

I found this https://github.com/juanmirocks/Levenshtein-MySQL-UDF, but I want to be sure that there are no alternatives.

Comment: PostgreSQL ships with one https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/fuzzystrmatch.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no single officially approved or universally accepted implementation as of writing this (May 2019). However, as suggested by [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james) in a comment,

> Search for `mysql Levenshtein`; there are several implementations out there. I don't know if they are all the same. A UDF implementation is likely to be faster than a Stored Procedure.